# imprimir el signo de '$' desde java, ya que cuando lo imprimo me aparece '¥'

Tags: java, android-studio

estimados deseo de su ayuda, estoy tratando de imprimir en una impresora termica el simbolo de '$' pero en la impresion me aparece el simbolo del yen '¥'
por ejemplo de salida deseada
**total $20**
salida Obtenida
**total ¥20**
adjunto una imagen del resultado obtenido
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void print_text(){
 outputStream = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
 printCustom("Subtotal: 25000");
 printCustom("IVA: 15%");
 printCustom("Total: C$2875");

}


private void printCustom(String msg) {
 byte[] cc = new byte[]{0x1B,0x21,0x03};  
 try {
   outputStream.write(cc);//size text
   outputStream.write(PrinterCommands.ESC_ALIGN_LEFT);
   outputStream.write(0x1C);outputStream.write(0x2E); 
   outputStream.write(0x1B);
   outputStream.write(0x74);
   outputStream.write(0x10);
   outputStream.write(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
   outputStream.write(PrinterCommands.LF);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Y cómo está llegando el dato correspondiente? A mí en java eso normalmente me pasaba cuando manipulaba variables sobre un OS trabajando con otro encoding. Que esté en yenes da a pensar incluso que puede estarte redondeando el monto (porque los yenes no tienen centavos)

Comment: @Alfabravo me podrias explicar, no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: Cómo estás generando el dato que le envías a la impresora? Es que, con decirle que el charset es ese, no va a bastar. El locale es el que condiciona el símbolo moneda y el separador de miles

Comment: he añadido la manera de como se genera el dato @Alfabravo